# How to join all data in table for one column as string with sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join all data in table. For example: I have a table like this,

```
ID     Name    ForeingId
----------------------
1       A        1
2       B        1
3       C        2
4       D        1
5       E        1
```

I want to get as a result the following with query. Such as 'SELECT ... WHERE ForeingId=1' .
I dont want to use procedure or function.

result : A,B,D,E

Comment: you are trying to do this in mysql/mssql ?

Comment: You can look at this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say. I am using MSSQL . Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MSSQL

I thank everyone for the answers. I found answer with link of @mehul9595's comment.

[Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

This way:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + t.name FROM table_name t
     where t.foreingId = 1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

For **ORACLE**, try this:

```
SELECT 
   LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS NAME
  FROM  TABLE
WHERE ForeingId= '1'
```